# How to set some custom variables in Shipment email

Tags: magento2.3

As I want to set some custom variables in Shipment email, For this I tried "email_shipment_set_template_vars_before" with Observer but I cannot access Order or Shipment related data in Observers variables PHP file, where I want to pass variables in transport object.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hey, I think you should be able to get the order like "$transport = $observer->getEvent()->getTransport(); $order=$transport['order'];" then access the normal stuff for example "$CustomerID = $order->getCustomerId();", I used this in "email_order_set_template_vars_before", but might be different tho

Comment: I need for shippment email.

Comment: Did you test it with that observer? It might work, if it doesn't, you do have access to the order increment id in that email, use it to get the order.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Your answer is not related what I need. But based on your answer, I can do something different way. But thank you very much for your feedback. At list I can get idea how to do form your feedback. It's save my lot time.

Comment: Hey, glad I could help you a bit to get what you needed, try to post the solution you found out as an answer and accept it, might help someone in the future